# How to open Xcode project which has objectVersion 38 with Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a Xcode project `MyProject.pbproj` in which a project file `project.pbxproj` has the property `objectVersion = 38;`

When I try to open it with Xcode, I get the message

> Failed to load project at '...', incompatible project version.

The version of my Xcode is 4.3.2

I'm new to the Xcode and complete Mac OS environment and I do not know what to do.

If my project is too old for my version of Xcode, is there any way to port my project to higher version of Xcode?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve a similar problem by doing this:

1. Create a new project in XCode.
2. Copy the source files (.m and .h) from the old project to the new project.
3. Use File > Add  Files to add those source files to the project.
4. Add some "#import" lines that seemed to be missing for some reason.
5. Convert the old project's .NIB file to a .XIB file:

   a. Open the .NIB file in XCode.

   b. Choose File > Duplicate.

   c. Choose File > Save. Choose .XIB format and overwrite the .XIB file of your new project.

Hope this helps. I'd love to know if there's a better way.

Good luck,
   Philip.