# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) on mac

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a xcode project,trying to open but issues while opening.

Initially while i got this -

```
Buntys-Mac-mini:~ bunty$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-  dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

So I tried this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799289/how-to-open-xcode-project-which-has-objectversion-38-with-xcode-4-3-2)

but still there is no success.
Is there any mistake while adding (.m and .h )files.
If that is the case then what is right procedure to open xcode project.
I am getting this error.

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Double-click on the `project.xcodeproj` file within *Finder* so it opens with Xcode?

Comment: Not opening.That was the first step.

Comment: So is Xcode installed?

Comment: Yes xcode is installed on my mac machine

Comment: Any error messages (see `Console.app`)?

Comment: This is the only error I have right now and I am not an iPhone developer...just want to do some small code modifications...can you please guide for this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84245/discussion-between-bunny-and-trojanfoe).